# generates null (read a word from file)

Tags: java, file, null

I'm trying to read a word from a file and display it in the console. Although the file contains text, the result is always `null`. What might be the error in the code?

Here is the code:

```
public class ParsingStrings{

private Scanner sc;
private static String input;

public void openFile(){
try{
    sc = new Scanner(new File ("E:\\Dropbox\\File.txt"));
    input = sc.next();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(input);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the openFile - method before printing the input to the console.

Comment: Yes, I'm an ass. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually called the method that opens the file and reads the input. So in your main method you're missing something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParsingStrings ps = new ParsingStrings();
    ps.openFile();

    System.out.println(input);

    }
```

Also in your `openFile()` you should check that your file has a next input to read.

```
if(sc.hasNext())
{
    input = sc.next();
}
```